# Make sure path doesn't go up a level

Tags: .net, validation, path

I want to make sure `relativePath` doesn't go up a folder past `basePath`.  Is there any reliable way to detect this?

```
string basePath = "/myfolder/";
string relativePath;

// Invalid
relativePath = "../foo";
relativePath = "subfolder/../../bar";

// Valid, but if too hard this can also be invalid
relativePath = "subfolder/../subfolder2";

// Valid
relativePath = "subfolder/another..folder/";
relativePath = "subfolder/..anotherFolder/";

// There may be ways to circumvent that I haven't thought of...
// Maybe some of these would work
relativePath = " ../";
relativePath = ".. /";

// fullPath should not be above basePath
string fullPath = basePath + relativePath;
```

I'm thinking something like the following could work

```
Path.GetFullPath(basePath + relativePath).StartsWith(basePath)
```

But I couldn't find a `VirtualPathUtility.GetFullPath()` or something similar.  I could disallow `../` anywhere in the string, but there may be a way to circumvent that with strange spacing, special characters, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) to convert all your paths to absolute paths, and then just compare the strings.  That is:

```
string basePath = "/myFolder/";
string relativePath = "whatever_user_inputs";

string basePathRooted = Path.GetFullPath(basePath);
string relativePathRooted = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);

if (!relativePathRooted.StartsWith(basePathRooted))
     //Fail
```

Comment: So `basePathRooted == "C:\myFolder"` and `relativePathRooted == "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\whatever_user_inputs"`.  I like your idea, though and `string relativePathRooted = Path.GetFullPath(basePath + relativePath)` should work.

Comment: Turns out I don't have the `basePath` ahead of time, so something like the following works well: `Path.GetFullPath(relativePath).StartsWith(Path.GetFullPath("."))`